# NSURLErrorDomain error

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm building an application with phonegap and I'm using the aviary plugin (www.aviary.com). When I try to open a photo taken by the camera, aviary plugin closes and "NSURLErrorDomain error -999" appears in the console log.
This problem doesn't appear when I try to open a web URL file (http://...)
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have all the appropriate URLs whitelisted.

See: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html#Domain%20Whitelist%20Guide

Comment: Are you using the html/js version of Aviary or a PhoneGap plugin?

Comment: If it's the html/js version... it might need to have a setting or two changed in Cordova.plist (OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView set to YES for instance)